# R - Connect to text file without opening in text editor

Tags: r, file, text-files, httpurlconnection

I need to repeatedly extract contents from a large number of text files with addresses given by URLs. Every time I run my R code and connect to a file it opens in Notepad++ which is my default text editor. The R code alone works perfectly well but in the text editor I have a "Reload" dialog window for each of 100+ files. How can I avoid this?

I use `url.show` function to extract the text and `file` function to connect and read the data.

```r
url.show('https://www.playok.com/p/?g=gm136365880&txt', file='game.txt')
con = file("game.txt", open = "r")
### some code: extracting lines of text and processing...
close(con)
```

Probably these are not the proper functions for my particular task. What I need is just a connection to the file contents without opening the file anywhere (including my RStudio window and the text editor window).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need a local copy of the file, you can just pass the URL to open:

```
con <- file("https://www.playok.com/p/?g=gm136365880&txt", open = "r")
readLines(con)
close(con)
```

will print the content of the URL